# Use pointer math instead of array indexing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to solve a problem found on my C programming book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *f (char s[], char t[], char out[]);
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "ISBN-978-8884981431";
    char t[] = "ISBN-978-8863720181";
    char out[10];
    printf ("%s\n", f(s,t,out));
    return 0;
}
char *f (char s[], char t[], char out[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; s[i] == t[i]; i++)
    out[i] = s[i];
out[i] = '\0';
return &out[0];
}
```

As you can see from the code, this code uses as return value &out[0]: does this means that the complete array is used as return value?

```
char *f (char s[], char t[], char out[]);
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "ISBN-978-8884981431";
    char t[] = "ISBN-978-8863720181";
    char out[10];
    printf ("%s\n", f(s,t,out));
    return 0;
}
char *f (char s[], char t[], char out[]) {
    for (; *(s+=1) == *(t+=1);)
            *(out+=1) = *s;
    *(out+1) = '\0';
    return out;
}
```

This is my proposed solution, but while the proposed code returns "ISBN-978-88", mine only returns "8".
The array is smaller than the lenght of the string, how the proposed code can work without any kind of overflow?
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: You're moving "out" forward. What you return is pointer to last character in your string (because ++out moves it character by character to the end).

Comment: with `*(out+1)='\0';`, you end the char array with NULL terminated character at index 1. Therefore, you can only see only 1 char when printing it out.

Comment: What you need to do is copy the initial value of `out` into another variable and return that in the end. Also, the `for` loop would typically be written as `while(*++s == *++t)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is too aggressive on side effects: the `+= 1` operation (which is more commonly denoted simply as `++`) should be applied after the copy to the output has been made, not after the comparison.

In addition, you need to save the value of the `out` buffer before incrementing the pointer, so that you could return a pointer to the beginning of the copied string.

```
char *orig = out;
for ( ; *s == *t ; s++, t++)
    *out++ = *s;
*out = '\0';
return orig;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/e1npRZ)

Comment: doesn't actually answer his issue, though I agree with the comments about over-use of side effects.

Comment: I didn't take in consideration the use of `out` as a buffer array and then return orign. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is returning a pointer to the end of the out array. Not the start. You need to stash the initial value of `out` and return that.

As an aside, the fact that you can do assignments inside a comparison doesn't mean it's a good idea. That code is going to be very hard to maintain.

Comment: It also skips the first character, since it increments both pointers before dereferencing and comparing.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen urg, so it does

Answer (score 2):

`&out[0]` is equivalent to `out`. Since arrays in C are passed by reference, in a sense, yes it does return the entire array.

Your solution only prints `"8"` because you're returning a pointer into the middle of the array. When it tries to print the string, it has no way of knowing that it's in the middle of the array/string, thus you only get a substring printed.

Comment: See others' answers - you basically need to keep the value of `out` before incrementing it, and return that original value.